# How to make the given component dynamic?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've found an Animated Scrolling component in the hero section of [This Website](https://preline.co/index.html). I want to know how to replicate the component and make it work as same as shown in the website with tailwind CSS. Please take a look into the given link. thank you

I am expecting the name of what such types of components are called and how to build one in tailwind CSS

Comment: look into css animations. make 3 vertical list like the link and for each list container apply your animation.

Comment: @innocent Whats the name of these type of components? can we find any prebuilt components?

Comment: [Take a look](https://pastebin.com/gaxYijJZ) into their classes, code etc...

Answer (score 0):

The animation wasn't made with Tailwind classes. If you look in the Developer Tools, you'll see that each column of pictures has a class of either `animation-sliding-img-up-1` or `animation-sliding-img-down-1`. You can also see that this class has this css:

```css
animation: sliding-img-up-1 30s linear infinite
```

This references these keyframes:

```css
0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
100% {
    transform: translateY(-722px);
}
```

Each column of images simply infinitely goes up and down, seamlessly.

For help on css animations, you can read this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations).